# QVariantList append

Tags: c++, qt, qvariant

I tri to append a QVariant to another QVariant (which must be a QVariantList).

> ```
> QList<int> listInt;
> listInt.append(1);    
> QVariant v;
> v.setValue(listInt);
> if(v.canConvert(QVariant::List))
> {
>     QVariant v1;
>     v1.setValue(5);
>     qvariant_cast<QVariantList>(v).append(v1);
> }
> objC.setProperty("_list", v);
> ```

But in the `obC` my `_list` contains only the integer 1.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the `qvariant_cast<>` returns by-value. So with your call to `append()` you are not changing the original object but only the copy. To make the changes stick, you will have to reset the QVariant, e.g.

> ```
>     ...
>     QVariantList toChange = qvariant_cast<QVariantList>(v);
>     toChange.append(v1);
>     v.setValue(toChange);
>     ...
> ```

or using `QList<int>` instead of `QVariantList`

> ```
>     ...
>     QList<int> toChange = qvariant_cast< QList<int> >(v);
>     toChange.append(47);
>     v.setValue(toChange);
>     ...
> ```

Comment: Ok. With your solution I have two items in `_list` but items are corrumpted (thay are not 1 and 5)

Comment: This answer was the first one. So I just place here a working example for you. Run it on your computer, not in ideone: http://ideone.com/nv9wYN

Comment: Your example works but, at the begining, I must have a QList<T> and at the end I must have also a QList<T> (and not a QVariantList).

Comment: Then you can put in QList<int> as the type parameter for the qvariant_cast and you should get the correct type back.

Comment: The problem is when I do the append I don't know the type T so I must only use generic type.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, what you are trying to do... You could make a template function with T as template parameter to do this. But this would of course fall flat if you were to try to add say an int to a QList<QString> this way. And if type T gets more complex you may have to make them known to Qt's meta type system.